# Differential equation using substitution

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following differential equation with a hint to solve of using the substitution of $u = \frac{y}{x}$:

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{(y/x)^3 + 1}{(y/x)^2}$$

I was wondering, after the substitution, what does the $\frac{dy}{dx}$ become? Is it just $\frac{dF}{du}$? i.e. some new function $F(u)$ with an independent variable $u$?

This is just a guess, could someone explain how the $\frac{dy}{dx}$ changes after the substitution and why?

Comment: The ODE will be of the form $u'(x) = F(u, x)$ with $F$ to be found. Note that you can differentiate $y(x) = u(x)x$ with respect to $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The substitution is made as $y=ux$, you just replace $y$ everywhere.

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{(y/x)^3 + 1}{(y/x)^2}$$
becomes
$$\frac{d(ux)}{dx} = \frac{((ux)/x)^3 + 1}{((ux)/x)^2}.$$
And using the rule for the derivative of a product

$$\frac{du}{dx}x+u\cdot1 = \frac{u^3 + 1}{u^2},$$
or
$$\frac{du}{dx}x = \frac1{u^2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

$u=\frac{y}{x}$ or $xu=y$ so $u+xu'=y'$ using the product rule on the left hand side.

Answer (score 0):

we have 
$u'x+u=\frac{u^3+1}{u^2}$
$u'x=\frac{1}{u^2}$
thus $u^2du=\frac{dx}{x}$